# Javascript not validating form correctly. Alert shown without user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

### Issue

I tried to validate this form by using the javascript below but even if I don't enter any values the alert will be shown only once and then the form will be submitted and the file will be created.

---

### Javascript

```
function validateForm() {
    console.log('the code is running');
    var firstName = document.forms.["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
    var lastName = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
    var gender = document.forms["myForm"]["Gender"].value;
    var eMail = document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
    var phoneNumber = document.forms["myForm"]["phoneNumber"].value;
    var information = document.forms["myForm"]["information"].value;

    if (firstName === null || firstName === ""){
          prompt("Please enter your First Name.");
          return false;
    }
    if (lastName == null || lastName == ""){
          alert("Please enter your Last Name.");
          return false;
    }
    if (gender == null){
          alert("Please Click on the button next to your gender");
          return false;
    }

    var atpos = eMail.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = eMail.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= eMail.length){
          alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
          return false;
      }
}
```

### PHP/HTML

```
<?php 
    if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit' ){
        echo "the Form has been submitted";
        $filename = $_POST['firstName'] . ".txt";
        $current = $_POST['firstName'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['lastName'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['Gender'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['Email'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['phoneNumber']
        . "\r\n" . $_POST['information'];
        file_put_contents($filename, $current);
    } 
?>

<form action="" name ="myForm" method=" post"onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="25" autofocus>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="25">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="Email" maxlength="35">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ask question and provide background information</td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="information" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="put your question and background information here"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit" onclick="javascript:return validateForm()"><input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: this is illegal `document.forms.["myForm"]` remove the period when using strings to get methods

Comment: you called lastName, gender, and gender instead of firstname, lastname, gender. and you have several typos.. all in all you didn't do too much debugging youself

Comment: I had a page with firstname, lastname and gender in.php page this probably happened in the .html page anyways now the program is running but it submits after throwing the error without letting me correct the details in the field. any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were able to debug it yourself and semi get it to run again. you need one more function to stop the form from submitting and thats `event.preventDefault()`

```
function validateForm (e) {
  // stops the form submitting
  (e || window.event).preventDefault();
  ...
  // all code in between

  ...
  document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
```

and in your html its as simple as just calling the function, you don't need to add javascript nor return;

```
<form ... onsubmit="validateForm()" ... >
```

btw remove the dot from in front of the bracket `document.forms.["myForm"]` to `document.forms["myForm"]`

#### Edit: solve the radio button validation

in your html

```
// avoid a null value by having a default value using checked attribute
<input type="radio" id="isMale" checked ... > Male
<input type="radio" id="isFemale" ... > Female
```

in your javascript replace your current validation with this

```
...
var isMale   = document.getElementById('isMale')
,   isFemale = document.getElementById('isFemale');
...
if (!isMale.checked && !isFemale.checked) {
  // user hasn't checked male nor female
  alert("Please Click on the button next to your gender");
  return false;
}
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7rp88/

Comment: everything is workin except the Gender validation part I just put the code provided by @RobG but its not working

Comment: @user3131961 my latest edit will validate for gender being checked

Comment: I kind of did the same thing but in a different way but urs is short so i will use yours thanks.

Comment: apparently you had this `onclick="javascript:return validateForm()"` in your submit button. it's not necessary because your using `onsubmit`. please refer to this link http://jsfiddle.net/7rp88/ as i put the code together and it validates as you wanted.

Comment: yes I have already corrected it and code is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos; you have `lastNmae` instead of `lastName`. Also, just make your submit button a button and remove the `onSubmit()` event handler, and call it via javascript's `form.submit()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="newcss.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function validateForm()
        {
            console.log('the code is running');
            var firstName = document.forms.["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
            var lastName = document.forms["myForm"]["Gender"].value;
            var gender = document.forms["myForm"]["Gender"].value;
            var eMail = document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
            var phoneNumber = document.forms["myForm"]["phoneNumber"].value;
            var information = document.forms["myForm"]["information"].value;


            if (firstName === null || firstName === ""){
                prompt("Please enter your First Name.");
                return false;
            }

            if (lastName == null || lastName == ""){
                alert("Please enter your Last Name.");
                return false;
            }

            if (gender == null){
                alert("Please Click on the button next to your gender");
                return false;
            }

            var atpos = eMail.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = eMail.lastIndexOf(".");

            if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= eMail.length){
                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                return false;
                }

        }
    </script>

        <?php if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit' ){
                    echo "the Form has been submitted";
        $filename = $_POST['firstName'] . ".txt";
        $current = $_POST['firstName'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['lastName'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['Gender'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['Email'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['phoneNumber']
            . "\r\n" . $_POST['information'];
        file_put_contents($filename, $current);
            } 
        ?>

        <form action="" name ="myForm" method="post">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="25" autofocus></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
                        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="Email" maxlength="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ask question and provide background information</td>
                    <td><textarea name="information" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="put your question and background information here"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" input type="button" onclick="validateForm();"/><input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the form is not validating

Comment: Should also pass *this* from the listener and receive it as *form* so the references can be shortened, e.g. `var firstName = form.firstName.value;` Also, form control values are strings so `firstNmae === null` will always be false, even when the typos are removed.

Comment: should it just be form.firstName.value or myForm.firstNmae.value? but if its always false then form should never be submitted but it is always submitted.

Comment: It should be whatever the name of the control is. Apart from the spelling, there is mis-alignment of control and variable names and the value for *gender* can't be accessed like that.

Comment: wait.. now it shows an error but after I click Ok it will not wait for me to reenter the data and will just submit the incomplete form

Comment: oh, I didn't realize you had an incomplete form. Just remove the form  submit and put it in a conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

In addition to scrblnrd3's answer, to get the value of *gender* you need something like:

```
 <td>Gender:</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
     <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
 </td>


var genderButtons = form.Gender;
var genderValue;

for (var i=0, iLen=genderButtons.length; i<iLen; i++) {

  if (genderButtons[i].checked) {
    genderValue = genderButtons[i].value;
  }
}

if (!genderValue) {
  // no gender button selected
}
```